# Facebook Group Feed Graph API Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read the documentation about retrieving a Facebook [groups feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed) but I am not understanding the second permission case they mention.

> A User access token of an Admin of the Group with the
>   user_managed_groups permission.
>
> An app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups
>   that belong to it.

I can get the feed of a closed group using my user access token successfully but I don't understand how to get the feed using the app access token as specified in the second case.

I've used the default App access token format 'AppID|AppSecret| but it complains about a permission missing.  What is the link between an App and a group, I think I am missing something to enable me to get a Group feed using a App token.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups that belong to it.

This isn't applicable any more.

App and Game Groups were a feature Facebook promoted for a while - apps could create groups, post to the group feed "as" the app, and invite users to it, to be able to create communities around games and stuff.

This feature has since been removed.

You can only read the feed of a closed group via API now if you are a group admin, resp. have their access token.

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I see others have already clarified the "App permission" part but something worthy to note is that the v2.12 update currently requires an admin user access token to read the group/feed endpoint among others. This is temporary and in the coming weeks it will return to allowing non-Admin permissions but restricting the amount of user information returned.

source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.12#gapi-90-groups

> GET /group — GET operations on the following fields and edges now require an access token of an Admin of the Group:
>
> [...]
>
> - GET /feed*
>
> [...]
>
> In the coming weeks, edges marked with an asterisk (*) will once again allow requests from non-Admin Group members. However, responses will not include User information unless the request is made with an access token of an Admin of the Group.

Comment: Yea I saw that but they haven't provided a date yet to when this is occurring.... It was released January 30, 2018 and they still haven't allowed access.  Any idea when it will be available or if they will notify users?